# Using Owin authentication middleware with mobile devices

Tags: .net, mobile, owin, oauth-2.0

I currently have SPA (angularjs) + .NET API as backend.

My backend should serve as service for multiple "front" application - SPA, native iOS & Android apps, etc.

For authentication I'm using Owin middleware (OAuth2 bearer tokens) with Resource Owner Password flow & also will be integrating social network logins - Facebook, Google, LinkedIn, etc.

Is it possible to use Owin middleware without cookies but also retain ability for social network integrations into mobile apps? All the Owin examples use something called "external cookie" which by the looks is just a cookie that is not being stored on my application but rather on fb/google during redirect.

Comment: Definitely possible - but the question is too broad.

Comment: you r already using token based authentication, not cookie. So it will work on mobile devices as well. All you have to do just keep the token server returned you when you login to the system